# forward ssh using port 80

Tags: apache-2.2, ssh, proxy

I need to forward everything that comes to `proxy.www.some.domain:80` to `10.0.0.101:22`
it is for forwarding ssh connection cause some of my friends are sitting behind **very** restrictive firewall which allows only connections to port `80`

is there any solution for that ?

Comment: what are you in china?

Answer (score 4):

[ssh-http-tunneling](http://dag.wieers.com/howto/ssh-http-tunneling/) is what you are looking for. Hope this helps you and your friend!

Comment: I was going to suggest pretty much the same thing, but you beat me to it!

Answer (score 0):

This should work ( not 100% sure, i wrote it on my iphone hehe)

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth0 -d xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 10.0.0.101:22

iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -i eth0 -d 10.0.0.101 --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

Comment: well this isn't what i need cause now with this everything on port is redirected to ssh. Even my normal website on www.some.domain and i wan't only connection to proxy.www.some.domain to be redirected...

Comment: Just simply put some source information in the forward statement so it only forwards that ip.